# ALTER TYPE Not Available So How To Alter a Type?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-table-type

I know there are other questions out there regarding this issue, but this one is really simple so I'm not looking for a complicated answer!

So I have this script:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types st JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE st.name = N'IDListTableType' AND ss.name = N'dbo')
DROP TYPE [dbo].[IDListTableType]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types st JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE st.name = N'IDListTableType' AND ss.name = N'dbo')
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IDListTableType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

I get an error when I run it because `IDListTableType` is referenced elsewhere in the database. So I need a way to either alter the table type in place, or to find and drop and recreate all other database objects that are referencing `IDListTableType`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Simplest would be to create a *new* type with the updated definition, then you can change the affected objects one at a time (or all at once) to reference the new name. You can’t pull the tablecloth.

I wrote an article about this here:

- [How to Alter User Defined Table Type in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6114/how-to-alter-user-defined-table-type-in-sql-server/)

The fundamental process is:

1. create a new type
2. determine which objects reference the old type
3. change those objects manually to point at the new type (or at least those objects that need to use the new type)
4. optionally, drop the old type

The tricky part is #2, people will hunt and peck manually, or try to parse `OBJECT_DEFINITION` or `sys.sql_modules`, but the following is a bit more reliable:

```
SELECT s.name, o.name, def = OBJECT_DEFINITION(d.referencing_id) 
  FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
     ON d.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
     ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE d.referenced_database_name IS NULL
    AND d.referenced_schema_name = N'dbo'
    AND d.referenced_entity_name = N'MyType';
```

Answer (score 4):

> So I need a way to either alter the table type in place, or to find
> and drop and recreate all other database objects that are referencing
> IDListTableType. Is there a simple way to do this?

First of all as [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242498/22336) pointed out and you are already, we cannot ALTER table type, we can CREATE & DROP it.

So to make any changes in existing `TABLE TYPE` you need to `DROP' it and execute CREATE TYPE statement with new definition.

> Find referencing objects.

You can use following query to find all objects referencing the table type.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),DEFINITION FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%IDListTableType%';
```

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IDListTableType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reference_table_type_1
AS
DECLARE @Table [dbo].[IDListTableType]
DECLARE @I int=1

WHILE @I<=10000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES(@I)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reference_table_type_2
AS
DECLARE @Table [dbo].[IDListTableType]
DECLARE @I int=10001

WHILE @I<=20000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES(@I)
END
```

Another way to find referencing objects is.

1. Go Object Explorer > Expend the database > Expand Programmability > Expend Types > User Defined Table Types.
2. Right click on the table type and click (left) on **View Dependencies**

Now you can generate script of all the objects, drop it and recreate after you update the table type.

Thanks!